# cannot import name 'objectives' from 'tensorflow.keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Facing error as below, while trying to import 'objectives' from 'tensorflow.keras'

```
from tensorflow.keras import objectives

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1708/2907996738.py in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras import objectives

ImportError: cannot import name 'objectives' from 'tensorflow.keras' (C:\Users\Sarang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py)

tf.__version__
'2.11.0'

keras.__version__
'2.11.0'
```

Comment: This module simply doesn't exist.

Comment: That module existed in Keras like 5 years ago (it was renamed), update your code to the latest imports.